# Java - Creating an instance of a class and then using it elsewhere

Tags: java

I have three classes that need to communicate with eachother: a `MainClass`, which will be the main running line; a `Maze` class, which will contain `MazeObject`s; and a `MazeObject` class, which will populate the maze. In my `MainClass`, I am creating a Maze object `Maze maze = new Maze()` , which will populate it with walls in its constructor. I am then trying to fill the maze with MazeObjects, from the same `MainClass`, by calling the `MazeObject` class, which has methods to do so. So my question is, how am I supposed to give the `MazeObject` class a copy of the maze so that it can populate it with maze objects?

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Maze maze = new Maze(); //This creates the new maze object
        MazeObject mazeObject = new MazeObject() //Populates the maze with tons of                                      different types of maze objects
```

How am I supposed to implement the MazeObject class so that it will be able to take the newly created maze in order to populate the maze?

Comment: Can you please post your code snippet for a little more clarity on what exactly you require?

Comment: I would imagine that the `Maze` is responsible for `MazeObject`s, not the other way around.  My guess is that `MazeObject` is either too broadly defined or doesn't need to exist.

Comment: @R.J I updated it. Anything else you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that, you can make a constructor that takes the maze like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Maze maze = new Maze();
    MazeObject mazeObject = new MazeObject(maze);
}
```

Maze object will have a reference to Maze like this

```
class MazeObject {
    private Maze maze;
    public MazeObject(Maze maze) {
        this.maze = maze;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I have to use this.maze for everything else in the class from then?

Comment: @bob No, I used it inside the constructor because the parameter is called `maze` too. Anywhere else in the class would be fine to just use `maze` instead of `this.maze`

Comment: Ok one more question, how can I then send this new maze, with all the MazeObjects back to the MainClass?

Comment: @bob Since your `MainClass` passes its `maze` reference to a `MazeObject`, the `maze` reference in `MazeObject` is referring to the *same* object in memory as the `maze` reference in `MainClass`. This means that modifying `maze` in one class will have the other class see those changes immediately, since they are looking at the same object.